# Obj C - resign first responder on touch UIView

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextview, hide

I'm trying to get the keyboard to disappear when the screen is touched, a question that is answered all over stackoverflow.  I was able to get the keyboard to disappear when the enter key was pressed thanks to a thread here.  I'm not having luck on the background touch resigning the first responder.  The method is being entered, I have an NSLog in the method saying, "in backgroundTouched" but the keyboard is still there.

I've tried making the UIView a UIControl class so I could use the touch event.
journalComment is a UITextView.

```
-(IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender
    {
        [journalComment resignFirstResponder];
        NSLog(@ "in backgroundTouched");

}
```

I've also tried having a invisible button under everything that calles the backGroundTouched method.  I think it maybe that I'm missing something in interface builder, but I'm not sure what.

Thank you for any help!

This is what works for the done button:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
 replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    // Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        // Be sure to test for equality using the "isEqualToString" message
        [textView resignFirstResponder];

        // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
        return FALSE;
    }
    // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Are you resigning first responder for all the input elements in the view?

Comment: It is a scroll view with three pages of buttons, "good mood, bad mood, etc" then a textview comment box.  Do I need to resign the buttons to since they are touched first.  I'll add the code that works for the done button up top.

Comment: Try resigning first responder for the scroll view too.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck on that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. We had this problem eariler, but eventually found the right solution.

```
  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

        [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];

        // you can have multiple textfields here


    }
```

This should resolve the problem with the keyboard not dissapearing when pushing the background.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for the newb question, but once I put that in my .m and .h file how do I tie it to the text field in interface builder?  Is that a ctrl drag from files owner to the text field selecting the UITextField I've created programmatically?

Comment: @rd42 You should just need to add that snippet to your .m file and it should work.

If not, feel free to add more of your code.

Comment: Ok if I figure out what other code would be helpful :) , I'll put it in.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following code works best with my text view (not text field) without the delegate methods:

first you set up a tap gesture recognizer onto your view :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self
                action:@selector(tap:)];
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

}
```

and then in your tap method :

```
- (void)tap:(id)sender
{
// use to make the view or any subview that is the first responder resign (optionally force)    
[[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

this should allow your keyboard to be dismissed when you anywhere on the view.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi xRab , good answer, thank you for your suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39306423/1894067) If you are always interested to this kind of thread, I've improve my code to the latest swift