# Using imageWithContentsOfFile: to load textures in spritekit

Tags: ios, uiimage, sprite-kit

So, I noticed this recommendation in one of the discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251337/ios-7-sprite-kit-freeing-up-memory?answertab=active#tab-top).
It says that in order to release memory once you done with the textures, a possible solution will be the next:

1. create UIImages with +imageWithContentsOfFile:
2. create SKTextures from the resulting UIImage objects by calling SKTexture/+textureWithImage:(UIImage*).

I have memory issues that comes from the high res backgrounds and few embedded scroll views, so I tried the above implementation - and it works in terms of memory.

The problem is that it looks like when doing so, imageWithContentsOfFile: in retina devices,  scales the @2x image by 2, so I need to explicit scale it again by 0.5.

How can I ensure the right scaling when calling this method?

Here is my code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sc_01_bg" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
SKSpriteNode *backgroundSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage: img]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is only upvote on that answer, and that upvote is mine. I can't remember now why I have upvoted that answer, because I've never experienced such problem.

If you still want to use the approach stated in that answer, you should use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]` instead of `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]`. Probably, UIKit doesn't automatically handle retina/non-retina images with `imageWithContentsOfFile:` method.

But basically you don't need that. Check LearnCocos2D's answer for that question.

PS: To free up a memory that have been used by `SKScene` just call

```
[self.skView removeFromSuperview];
self.skView = nil;
```

Comment: The problem is "imageNamed:" cached the texture. I am not sure it is a good idea to work with few skviews, at list from what I read.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "I am not sure it is a good idea to work with few skviews"?