# How to remove SKTexure after animation

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm using SKTextures

```
var texture1 = SKTexture()
var texture2 = SKTexture()
```

and SKActions

```
SKAction.animate(with:[texture1, texture2])
```

for animate SKSpriteNodes in my game.

But when animation is done, memory contains textures. How can I remove all textures from memory after animation is done?
When I come to another SKScene memory are free, but I need free memory before transition.
Sorry for my English
Im using SWIFT 3

Comment: How do you know the textures are still in memory?  if anything, it is possible for texture2 to be in memory depending on settings you select to allow it to reset the texture when finished or not.

Comment: is var texture1 global?  You may have to do var texture1 = nil, but you would need to make them optional for that

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Doing var texture1 = nil don't solve the problem: the texture is resident on the cache system.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano people keep talking about this "cache system" but I do not believe it is a cache in the way people are believing it is.  I am going to have to experiment when I can into this manner.  I would figure it is a weak reference holding onto an SKTexture, but we know that is not the case because of a different discussion we had when imageNamed was bugged, and produced more objects.  I have had many of chats with apple tier 1 engineers,  and let me tell you, they are very quick to hit that resolved nothing is wrong button, so due to experience I can't believe what they say either

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Look my answer: it's the doc that explain the SKTexture behavior's. It stay resident in memory (cache system probably..it's not specified but it could be that) and you do not have to worry about managing SKTexture because it's the task of apple. Your task is to follow tips reported to "Managing Texture Memory" chapter (avoid loading too many textures in a single pass..). We have not invented words, are terms derived from the manual.I would like to tell you is true, memory management would truly better, unfortunately the reality is different.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano you are reading too much into that,  that does not talk about any kind of caching system, that is actually backing up what I am saying,  if all of the strong references are killed, that SKTexture should die.  The rendering portion has to do with transferring texture data to VRAM.  Now if you are telling me that setting a texture to nil does not remove it from memory, but removing the node does, then that right there is a flag that it is a bug with SKSpriteNode, and that bug I can actually explain.  The animation action can retain the original texture before animating

Comment: and in this process, may be why an SKTexture is being held when the developer has no strong references to it.

Comment: About "texture to nil" I've only said : the texture is resident on the cache system.
You are attributing the memory management for SKTexture to the canonical method of memory administration adopted for the other nodes: who says that Apple has not introduced a different data rescue system? It does not allow you to remove SKTexture's, there aren't sources, don't you find this should make you think about it? Believe me, I would agree with you but at present we can only reason about on.

Comment: Otherwise, since this topic is very interesting, you could shows that you can remove SKTexture without any problem, and I will post your results in all over StackOverflow under related topics (I'm sorry for my english error..)

Comment: Wrote the sample, it is in the chat I sent you an invite to @AlessandroOrnano I was right,  removing all strong references from the developers side of things will remove it from the cache and memory as well

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Very good, here in Italy it's too late (night) so tomorrow I'll try all tests, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124848/discussion-between-alessandro-ornano-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Hello man :( , I don't receive any invite, can you send my another one?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon No invite until now, how can I see your code?

Comment: weird,  look for the SpriteKit chatroom on here

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124357/sprite-kit

Comment: @Knight0fDragon This chat don't speak about texture, are you sure this is the correct link?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano no idea if you got notified, check again I reposted it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok test ended, now I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok do it. Please write an answer with your code.

Comment: Hi guys! I'm not found the solve of my problem( 
Memory contains textures everytime. But I can free memory from SKTexture when I have transition to another SKScene with remove SKSpriteNode who have animation.
somenode.removeFromParent()
sorry for my english

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I invite you in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125234/opinions-from-sktexture-and-others

Answer (score 0):

Textures may not be released from memory due to caching system.

You could use the `completion` when you run your action for example:

```
self.run(SKAction.animate(with:[texture1, texture2]), completion: {
   //animation is ended, do other stuff
})
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21541819/1894067) answer for more detail.

From the official [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sktexture):

> The texture data is prepared for rendering when:
>
> A sprite or particle that uses the texture is part of a node tree that
>   is being rendered.
>
> Once the SKTexture object is ready for rendering, it stays ready until
>   all strong references to the texture object are removed. ...
>
> None of
>   these textures must be loaded because their data **is already in memory
>   when the texture is created**. However, the texture must still be
>   prepared by SpriteKit before it can be used for rendering.

There are no options (for now - Swift 3) to directly deallocated these texture from memory. Anyway remain just `nil` assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the your reply. But I know about that and type SKTexture has no member removeFromParent() (((

Comment: Sorry I mean nodeWithTexture, I've update my answer.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano you are still removing the node, he just wants to remove the texture

Comment: As I said guys you cannot remove from memory the sktexture so the only solution is or to remove the node or to do other stuff

Comment: I am almost positive I debunked that,  but it may have been a different issue,  I am not bothering to find it.  How would removing the node remove it from memory,  but not setting it to nil?